# Skipping/modifying trac authetication module

Tags: trac

I am looking to modify the trac login part. My requiremnt is like this
I have one website X which uses an existing SSO for its authentication but my requirement is I want to login trac on the basis of the fact if user is logged in on website X that time. i tried exploring trac but I could find that it looks for basic or digest authentication . I am really confused how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Trac itself does not handle authentication.  It delegates that job to the web server.  If you can configure your web server to respect your SSO scheme, then you shouldn't have to do anything special with Trac.  Unfortunately, I can't give you any specific details because there are many different ways to do SSO and I don't know how your particular system implements it.

It is also possible to use a plugin to handle Trac authentication, such as the [AccountManagerPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AccountManagerPlugin).  If you are unable to use web server configuration alone to solve your problem, you may be able to adapt the plugin to use your SSO mechanism as a backend.  Again, this will all depend on your particular SSO methodology.